# RoR: Table doesn't exist error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am new here and with RoR. I sit for 5 hours and dont get it whats wrong with my program. I followed strict a tutorial and this happened:

Ruby Version: 2.2.4
Rails Version: 5.0.0.1
devise Version: 4.2.0

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'rubyandroid_development.users' doesn't exist: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_users_on_authentication_token`  ON `users` (`authentication_token`) 
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160826225028_devise_create_users.rb:12:in `block in change'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160826225028_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'rubyandroid_development.users' doesn't exist: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_users_on_authentication_token`  ON `users` (`authentication_token`) 
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160826225028_devise_create_users.rb:12:in `block in change'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160826225028_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: Table 'rubyandroid_development.users' doesn't exist
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160826225028_devise_create_users.rb:12:in `block in change'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160826225028_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
== 20160826225028 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:users)
-- add_index(:users, :authentication_token, {:unique=>true})

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the db/migrate/ devise_create_users code:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      t.string :name, :null => false, :default => ""

      #token hinzugefügt
      t.string :authentication_token
      add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true


      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Here is db/migrate add_devise_to_users

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

UPDATE: I forgot to uncommend the line: 
      add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true. But now when I do rake db:migrate, the following Error occurs:

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160827004755_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160827004755_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160827004755_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160827004755_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160827004755_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/db/migrate/20160827004755_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/RubyAndroid/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
== 20160827004755 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
```

Comment: Which tutorial have you followed? Your error message says, you have not created users table and applying index on a particular column of a table which does not exist.

Comment: Here is the Tutorial I followed: http://lucatironi.net/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/      this tutorial uses authentication_token, which is deprecated. So i installed a gem for this ( gem 'devise-token_authenticatable')

Comment: Can you please tell Rails version and Devise gem version ?

Comment: can you please add the migration that doesn't want to pass?

Comment: How can i see what Devise gem version I have?

Comment: Gemfile.lock states the version.

Comment: ok thanks: devise (4.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have two migration files for this as you should only really need the first one. The first one contains the following line

```
add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
```

in the `create_table` block when it shouldn't do. I think moving that line to the line beneath that block (so that it sits outside of `create_table` but within the `change` block with the other `add_index` lines) should fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the problem. I forgot to uncommend this line. But now there arises another Problem when I want to use rake db:migrate:   Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Comment: I think you're getting that error because of the second migration file (it's attempting to add columns that already exist..looks like the syntax is a bit off as well). Try running `rake db:rollback`. If that runs correctly,  delete the add_devise_to_users migration. You may want to run  `rake db:migrate` again after that, just in case.

Comment: KohrVid, I thank you very much! But now there is another very big Problem arising,I think I need to skip this tutorial..It shows me NoMethodError: undefined method 'authentication_token_created_at'.                      I think this method is deprecated and on the internet there is no method for this so I cannot add this to my program

Comment: Your first migration didn't contain that column. You could either try rolling it back and adding it in or try generating a new migration file (`rails g migration AddAuthenticationTokenCreatedAtToUsers`) with the following line: `add_column :users, :authentication_token_created_at, :datetime`. Running `rake db:migrate` again after that should add the column to the table.

Comment: Hey KohrVid, I thank you so much! But now I'm getting stuck at the part where you test the login with curl. It says: //ArgumentError (Before process_action callback: verify_authenticit_token has not been defined) //                                                                                                    I used this code:   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

Comment: That may have just been cause by another typo. The error message you're getting states that "verify_authenticit_token" hasn't been defined but the method you should be using is called "verify_authenticit**y**_token".

Comment: sorry I forgot an y on my post. I still get the message and I dont know why: ArgumentError (Before process_action callback: verify_authenticity_token has not been defined)

Comment: I think that I would need to see the controller that this was added to (and possibly the routes created) to be sure. Have you checked that the controllers have been set up to inherit from Devise like they do in the tutorial you're using?